# how to login to facebook from app login button?

Tags: android, facebook

i want to open Facebook login page by clicking on login button of my app and then after login i want to open my frnd list. but every time something went wrong. i am using this code

```
loginTofacebook() {
                mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

            if (access_token != null) {
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
           loginbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if (expires != 0) {
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }

            if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                facebook.authorize(this,
                        new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                        new DialogListener() {
                                    @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                                        editor.putString("access_token",facebook.getAccessToken());
                                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                                editor.commit();
}}
```

Comment: you should have to get all friends by using facebook sdk. and show all fiends in our application

Comment: use this link to connect with facebook http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open login browser page of Facebook in your application, you have to integrate Facebook-SDK properly.

Please prefers some important links for it.

[Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

[Link](https://github.com/crowjdh/android-facebook-like-button-integration/tree/master/facebook-like-sample/src/com/yooiistudios/chris)

[Link](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/)